# View with the textField doesn't shows up

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view at the bottom of the mainView, called "newMessageArea". That view contains a textfield. The problem is that i have tried a method that makes the view with the textfield comes up when the textfield shows up... But for some reason, it doesn't work...
Here is what i tried...
(ViewDidLoad)

```
bottomCOnstraint = newMessageArea.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
    bottomCOnstraint.isActive = true

    let messageAreaConstrains : [NSLayoutConstraint] = [

        newMessageArea.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        newMessageArea.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        newMessageArea.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newMessageField.heightAnchor, constant: 20),

        newMessageField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newMessageArea.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        newMessageField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newMessageArea.centerYAnchor),
        newMessageField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leadingAnchor, constant: -10),

        sendButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newMessageArea.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        sendButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newMessageField.centerYAnchor),

    ]

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(messageAreaConstrains)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(ChatViewController.keyboardWillShow(notification:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow,
        object: nil
    )
```

This is the method...

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo,

        let frame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue,

        let animationDuration = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).doubleValue {

        let newFrame = view.convert(frame, from: (UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window)!)

        bottomCOnstraint.constant = newFrame.origin.y - view.frame.height

        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: {

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        })
    }
}
```

So, what can i do?
Thanks

Comment: Call `self.view.updateConstraints()`

Comment: Where do i call it??

Comment: After you set constraints, before you call `layoutIfNeeded()`.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The "newMessageArea" is not coming up with when the textfield shows up

Comment: Try setting `bottomCOnstraint.constant` to something like 200 and see if perhaps it's putting it outside the view? You can also use Xcode's view inspector to blow up your view hierarchy and see where it is.